# Transactions on BscScan don't add up

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, bsc

I'm creating a web application for which I want to log transactions specific to a single wallet and a single token on the BSC network.

I would like to do this programmatically by using the bscScan API. Now when I query this API of theirs for requesting transaction history I get the same results as can be seen in the url below (this is the history for a token called Safemoon for my wallet address 0x2ac7809a2a046fb347debc998ed16ec89495ea51):
https://bscscan.com/token/0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3?a=0x2ac7809a2a046fb347debc998ed16ec89495ea51

Now if I add and subtract all these transactions, I would conclude that my balance of this Safemoon token should be 1079881822 SAFEMOON.

But I **know** this is not correct...Because the actual amount of Safemoon that is in my wallet is 2,382,699.325561183 . I know this because both the bscScan wallet overview, as well as metamask say so. Also, when I interact with the Safemoon smart contract by calling the balanceOf function through Web3, it tells me the same amount.
So the only thing I can imagine is that there must be one or more significant transactions missing. Does anybody have an idea as to which info is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. There's a separate swap function:

https://bscscan.com/tx/0x23e65276304a7b20c511e539ac350a38978710ae10734cc209af4e2e4be5a15a#eventlog

[image]

Which burns the tokens. So the value in your wallet is the sum of the transactions - burn %.

Hence to get the current balance you'll need to manually call the getBalance() function on the contract.